# JavaScript new Function scope ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, function, scope, referenceerror

is there any way to make the code below working?

```
(function(){
    var n = "abc";
    (new Function("return alert(n);"))();
})();
```

If I run the code in browser result is: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined**".

Also, I need to some other variables like "n" make accessible inside the "new Function" too.

Please help, 
Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `new Function` at all in this case? There is a big yellow note in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), it can hardly be overlooked: *"**Note:** Functions created with the `Function` constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope. [...]"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need to make that variables global.

```js
(function(){
    window.n = "abc";
    (new Function("return alert(n);"))();
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use the `new Function` method (which is similar to `eval` by the way), your code is executed in the *global* scope!  `n` only exists inside that anonymous function, it's not global.

You shouldn't be using `new Function` unless it's 100% necessary.

```
(function(){
    var n = "abc";
    (function(){return alert(n);})();
})();
```

P.S. `alert` returns `undefined` so `return alert()` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable as a parameter to the created function.

```
(function(){
    const myVar = 1000;
    (new Function("return alert(n);"))(myVar);
})();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).